# Extracting the first two characters from an R string with variable length

Tags: r, regex

I need to extract the first two unique characters from a variable in an R dataframe and assign them to a new variable. The challenging part is that the number of times these two letters can appear changes. An example of where I'm starting and where I'd like to end:

```
df<-data.frame(have=c("SSNAAAB","SSSSAAAABAS","SSAABNAX","SAAXS","AASBNA","BBBBBNNA"))
df$want<-c("SSN","SSSSAAAA","SSAA","SAA","AAS","BBBBBNN")
```

I think regex may be the solution but haven't yet learned how to use regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is fairly straightforward with regex:

`^(.)\1*(.)\2*`

https://regex101.com/r/yS81Mn/1

Explanation:

1. `^` Start matching at the beginning of the string
2. `(.)` Match any character and capture it as group 1
3. `\1` Match the character stored in group 1
4. `*` Continue matching any number of times
5. `(.)\2*` Same as steps 2 through 4

Comment: In R, that would be `stringr::str_extract(df$have, "^(.)\\1*(.)\\2*")`

Comment: That worked beautifully. One follow-up: I have some "have" values with 1 character. The current code (as implemented by @RonakShah) makes those values with 1 character become NA.

Comment: If you need to also match single character strings, you can simply add `?` after the 2nd group, i.e. `^(.)\1*(.)?\2*`

Comment: That fix didn't work perfectly but I coupled it with a (if nchar(have)==1) then want<-have, else (your solution). Works great.